# React Router with array of paths + exact still initializes components when location does not match

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React Router v5. We have a setup where there are 2 possible routes to render `Component1`, and a single route to render `Component2`. However, in my test, it is initializing `Component1` unexpectedly.

```
const UsersRoutes: FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location)
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={[routes.admin.users.root, routes.admin.users.import]} >
        {console.log('hi there i should not log') // I would not expect this to be called}
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Route path={routes.admin.users.user.root()}>
        <UserRoutes />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

In my test:

```
describe('<User />', () => {
  test('user root redirects to profile', async () => {
    const { findByText, history, findByLabelText } = renderWithRouter(
      <UsersRoutes />,
      {
        route: routes.admin.users.user.root(testId),
      }
    );

    expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual(`/admin/users/${testId}/profile`);
    await findByText('profile');
    await findByLabelText('profile');
  });
});
```

Console output:

```
console.log src/screens/App/screens/Admin/screens/Users/routes.tsx:9
    actual location hook:  {
      pathname: '/admin/users/123-test',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: undefined,
      key: 'kdljhy'
    }

  console.log src/screens/App/screens/Admin/screens/Users/routes.tsx:14
    hi there i should not log

  console.log src/screens/App/screens/Admin/screens/Users/routes.tsx:9
    actual location hook:  {
      pathname: '/admin/users/123-test/profile',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: undefined,
      key: 'zdaam2'
    }

  console.log src/screens/App/screens/Admin/screens/Users/routes.tsx:14
    hi there i should not log
```

So, how does the `exact` attribute when using an array of paths matching work?  Is this really expected?  Nothing about the logs of the `location` indicate that this path should have been matched.

Comment: FWIW when you are console logging as an unintentional side-effect you can't really determine what React is *actually* doing. In other words, using `console.log` outside lifecycle methods and hooks generally isn't a good measure for anything. Here the console.log is simply executed because the entire returned JSX needs to be processed and the log is a side-effect, it's nothing to do with route matching and rendering.

Answer (score 0):

As per React ReactTraining, this is the expected behavior:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7726#issuecomment-750755953